# How to share a dependency that isn't in Clojars

Tags: clojure, dependency-management, leiningen

I need to use the [mongo-storm](https://github.com/christkv/mongo-storm) library and Clojars doesn't [have it](http://clojars.org/search?q=mongo-storm). So I cloned the project, compiled and copied the jar to my lib folder by hand. But it is a team project and it is unacceptable for every member to do those steps by hand.

Are there any better and standard ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: You can also use "lein install" to make the dependency available locally on your computer. You can then use it from another project the usual way. (No need to copy jars manually.) This might not be convenient for a team, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your team should have a private repository for this purpose.  S3 is an ideal substrate for this, and you can use the s3-wagon-private Leiningen plugin to deploy and consume artifacts to/from a secured S3 bucket:

https://github.com/technomancy/s3-wagon-private

Answer (score 2):

If the project has a license that allows it (if it's open source) you are allowed to push your own unofficial version to Clojars yourself using your own group ID. Clojars reserves the "org.clojars.username" group IDs for this purpose. This is described in https://github.com/ato/clojars-web/wiki/tutorial and https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/DEPLOY.md .

The best way would probably be if you could contact the author and to urge him/her to do a proper release. (Also, the readme doesn't tell what license the project has.)

Answer (score 2):

A solution that doesn't require setting up a private repository would be to leverage the [checkouts](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L59) capability in leiningen.

Comment: My lein version is 1.7 , checkouts are lein 2 feature

Comment: Look at 1.7.1 sources, it's indeed [supported](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/1.7.1/src/leiningen/classpath.clj#L22)

Comment: Correct, checkouts have been around for a long time. But using an S3-based repo is much better for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if your team is using a maven based dependency management system (like Leiningen), you would have a repository manager set up.  You can then deploy the library to your team's repository manager.

Most repository managers have Maven Central already included and make it easy to both add additional repositories to proxy (e.g. Clojars) and host your own repositories (for mongo-storm and the project being developed).

After getting one set up, one of the things you'll want to make sure your team does is either set as a repository proxy or as an additional repository to pull jars from.

You can find a list of repository managers on the [maven site](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html).